Is Betting money on stopping a sin Haram?
Al salam alykum, i wanted to ask:
If you and a friend struggle from a haram addiction (may got forgive us) and both want to stop. Is it halal to make a wager on who can go the longer without doing this sin?

Alhamdulillah,
Our motivation to stay away from sins and unlawful actions should stem from the fear of Allah, love for His pleasure, and strengthening our faith - not driven by a temporal bet or wager.
There are better and purer ways to encourage and support each other in abstaining from sins, such as making sincere intentions, doing istighfar (seeking Allah's forgiveness), and holding each other accountable through reminders and advice.
Instead of a wager, I would advise that you and your friend make a pact or agreement to help each other quit this addiction through halal means:

Make du'a for one another and for Allah to ease your affairs.
Remind each other of the harms of the sin and rewards of abstaining.
Reduce situations/environments that enable the sinful behavior.
Replace it with beneficial activities and good company.
Be patient, supportive and do not lose hope in Allah's mercy.
Encourage each other with gifts/prizes prizes for avoiding the sin.

May Allah purify your hearts, guide you both to that which is pleasing to Him, and grant you success in overcoming this struggle. Have faith and persevere through halal means.
And Allah knows best!
